# OpenJPA does not find Entities

Tags: java, jpa, entity, openjpa, persistence.xml

I am currently using OpenJPA in one of my projects and got yet another problem.
I defined some entities in my persistence.xml but OpenJPA doesnt seem to find them.
While running my project I got this warning for every single entity registered in my persistence.xml:

> WARN   [http-nio-8080-exec-3] openjpa.MetaData - The class
>   "Entitiy.Employee" listed in the
>   openjpa.MetaDataFactory configuration property could not be loaded by
>   ParallelWebappClassLoader`

And than I get this error:

> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: An error occurred
>   while parsing the query filter "SELECT e FROM Employee e". Error
>   message: The name "Employee" is not a recognized entity or identifier.
>   Known entity names: []

Seems to me like not a single one of my entities declared in my persistence.xml can be found.

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="PesUnit">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>Entitiy.Employee</class>
        ... all other classes listed the same way...
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults" value="ForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict, JoinForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somescheme"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="user"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="pass"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: you have spelt `Entity` as `Entitiy`.  might that be the problem?

Comment: No thats not the problem, it actually was a mistake but fixing it didnt change the outcome.

Comment: Could this have to do anything with my Entities not getting enhanced?

Comment: are you annotating the entities with the `@Entity` annotation?  can you show the code of the Employee entity?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already found my solution. The package containing my Entities is called "Entities" not "Entity". Sorry that I didnt notice that before posting.